# Component is not showing up on the React page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I have problem with 2 js files called Card.js and Home.js. The entire Home page is showing up except for the Card Component.
The Card component is supposed to fetch data from the database and show up the details of a specific food item. The backend has been set up and it is connected to my database.

I have tried removing the complicated js code, importing the normal Card.js file and use it using  , but getting a White Screen of Death. I don't consider it as a good option because removing the logic will spoil the entire functionality of the component.

Home.js -

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Card from '../components/Card'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
export default function Home() {
  const [foodCat, setFoodCat] = useState([])
  const [foodItems, setFoodItems] = useState([])
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const loadFoodItems = async () => {
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/foodData", {
  
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }

    });
    response = await response.json()
    // console.log(response[1][0].CategoryName)
    setFoodItems(response[0]) // food items
    setFoodCat(response[1])   // food category , display data has the function 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadFoodItems()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div >
      <div>
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <div>
        <div id="carouselExampleFade" className="carousel slide carousel-fade " data-bs-ride="carousel">

          <div className="carousel-inner " id='carousel'>
            <div class=" carousel-caption  " style={{ zIndex: "9" }}>
              <div className=" d-flex justify-content-center">  {/* justify-content-center, copy this <form> from navbar for search box */}
                <input className="form-control me-2 w-75 bg-white text-dark" type="search" placeholder="Search in here..." aria-label="Search" value={search} onChange={(e) => { setSearch(e.target.value) }} />
                <button className="btn text-white bg-danger" onClick={() => { setSearch('') }}>X</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="carousel-item active" >
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x700/?burger" className="d-block w-100  " style={{ filter: "brightness(30%)" }} alt="..." />
            </div>
            <div className="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x700/?pastry" className="d-block w-100 " style={{ filter: "brightness(30%)" }} alt="..." />
            </div>
            <div className="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x700/?barbeque" className="d-block w-100 " style={{ filter: "brightness(30%)" }} alt="..." />
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span className="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span className="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
          </button>
          <button className="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span className="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span className="visually-hidden">Next</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      
      <div className='container'> 
        {
      foodCat !== []
            ? foodCat.map((data) => {
              return (
                
                // justify-content-center
                 <div className='row mb-3'>
                  <div key={data.id} className='fs-3 m-3'>
                    {data.CategoryName}
                  </div>
                  <hr id="hr-success" style={{ height: "4px", backgroundImage: "-webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgb(0, 255, 137),rgb(0, 0, 0))" }} />
                  {foodItems !== [] ? foodItems.filter(
                    (items) => (items.CategoryName === data.CategoryName) && (items.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())))
                    .map(filterItems => {
                      return (
                        <div key={filterItems.id} className='col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3'>
                          {console.log(filterItems.url)}
                          <Card foodName={filterItems.name} item={filterItems} options={filterItems.options[0]} ImgSrc={filterItems.img} ></Card>
                        </div>
                      )
                    }) : <div> No Such Data </div>}
                </div> 
              )
            }) 
            : ""
        }        
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Card.js -

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatchCart, useCart } from './ContextReducer'
export default function Card(props) {
  let data = useCart();

  let navigate = useNavigate()
  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)
  const [size, setSize] = useState("")
  const priceRef = useRef();
  let options = props.options;
  let priceOptions = Object.keys(options);
  let foodItem = props.item;
  const dispatch = useDispatchCart();
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      navigate("/login")
    }
  }
  const handleQty = (e) => {
    setQty(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleOptions = (e) => {
    setSize(e.target.value);
  }
  const handleAddToCart = async () => {
    let food = []
    for (const item of data) {
      if (item.id === foodItem._id) {
        food = item;

        break;
      }
    }
    console.log(food)
    console.log(new Date())
    if (food !== []) {
      if (food.size === size) {
        await dispatch({ type: "UPDATE", id: foodItem._id, price: finalPrice, qty: qty })
        return
      }
      else if (food.size !== size) {
        await dispatch({ type: "ADD", id: foodItem._id, name: foodItem.name, price: finalPrice, qty: qty, size: size,img: props.ImgSrc })
        console.log("Size different so simply ADD one more to the list")
        return
      }
      return
    }

    await dispatch({ type: "ADD", id: foodItem._id, name: foodItem.name, price: finalPrice, qty: qty, size: size })


  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setSize(priceRef.current.value)
  }, [])


  let finalPrice = qty * parseInt(options[size]);   //This is where Price is changing

  return (
    <div>

      <div className="card mt-3" style={{ width: "16rem", maxHeight: "360px" }}>
        <img src={props.ImgSrc} className="card-img-top" alt="..." style={{ height: "120px", objectFit: "fill" }} />
        <div className="card-body">
          <h5 className="card-title">{props.foodName}</h5>
          {/* <p className="card-text">This is some random text. This is description.</p> */}
          <div className='container w-100 p-0' style={{ height: "38px" }}>
            <select className="m-2 h-100 w-20 bg-success text-black rounded" style={{ select: "#FF0000" }} onClick={handleClick} onChange={handleQty}>
              {Array.from(Array(6), (e, i) => {
                return (
                  <option key={i + 1} value={i + 1}>{i + 1}</option>)
              })}
            </select>
            <select className="m-2 h-100 w-20 bg-success text-black rounded" style={{ select: "#FF0000" }} ref={priceRef} onClick={handleClick} onChange={handleOptions}>
              {priceOptions.map((i) => {
                return <option key={i} value={i}>{i}</option>
              })}
            </select>
            <div className=' d-inline ms-2 h-100 w-20 fs-5' >
              ₹{finalPrice}/-
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr></hr>
          <button className={`btn btn-success justify-center ms-2 `} onClick={handleAddToCart}>Add to Cart</button>
          {/* <button className={`btn btn-danger justify-center ms-2 ${btnEnable ? "" : "disabled"}`} onClick={handleRemoveCart}>Remove</button> */}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: No, both the frontend and the backend are working on their allotted ports

Comment: Does `console.log(filterItems.url)` show what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

At least one issue is this bit of code: `foodCat !== []`.  Arrays, functions and objects are reference types. Variables of reference types store references to their data, while variables of value types directly contain their data.

So here you're trying to compare the array that the foodCat state variable references with the new array that you're creating in that expression.  They will never be the same and this will always be true.

If you want to make sure that foodCat is not referencing an empty array before you map or filter it, you can use: `foodCat.length !== 0` or `!!foodCat.length`.

```js
const foodCat = []
console.log(foodCat !== []) // true
console.log(!!foodCat.length) // false
console.log(foodCat.length !== 0) // false
```